# Books used for self-learning in Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

Were you ever able to locate a good book to self-teach yourself Trigonometry?

Thanks...

Comment: Khan Academy: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry is always a great resource. If you're starting off, most elementary textbooks have trigonometry sections. You can also type in "Trigonometry Books PDF" to get resources such as https://www.stitz-zeager.com/szct07042013.pdf.

Comment: Cohen's precalculus book is pretty good.

Comment: What languages can you read, and how good is your algebra background?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the community. As JC12 commented, Khan Academy is always a good source. However, let me recommend you some books:

- Elementary Trigonometry, Durell & Wright, 1926
- Advanced Trigonometry, Durell and Robson, 1930

Don't forget to take a look at Khan's material and compare!

Comment: These books can be downloaded from http://knowledge-dojo.com .